# Parse Facebook Login Integration Handling Invalidated Session

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, facebook-login, parse-server

I was wondering if anyone knows the updated code in swift3 for the following. I got this from the Parse Server github(link below).

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
    // handle successful response
} else if ([[error userInfo][@"error"][@"type"] isEqualToString: @"OAuthException"]) { // Since the request failed, we can check if it was due to an invalid session
    NSLog(@"The facebook session was invalidated");
    [PFFacebookUtils unlinkUserInBackground:[PFUser currentUser]];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Some other error: %@", error);
}
```

}];

Specifically, I want to understand what to check for in

```
"[[error userInfo][@"error"][@"type"] isEqualToString: @"OAuthException"]".
```

I understand if swift3 I want to set that as

```
"if error = (error as? NSError!).userInfo[something]"
```

But I'm not sure which argument I need to pass through in userinfo[]. E.g. FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey, FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphError, etc.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/wiki/Integrate-Login-with-Facebook

Comment: Sorry i miss understood what you where asking!

Comment: @Cliffordwh no problem!

Answer (score 0):

API will return an HTTP 400 status code, a code and a subcode in a JSON body explaining the nature of the error.   In your case the invalid session. Just cast that to a variable and check if its equal to `"OAuthException"` .

```
{
      "error": {
        "message": "Error validating access token: The session is invalid 
                    because the user logged out.", 
        "type": "OAuthException", 
        "code": 190
      }
    }
```

Comment: I saw this on the Facebook developers site as well. How would I make this so that it fits the "error.userInfo" format in swift?